# Convert date and time into Correct format to compare to current date

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a date in this format "2017-03-29" and time like "09:30", How do I conver toDatetime.

Following is how  I have

```
string date = "2017-03-29";
string time  = "09:30"
```

I need to convert this to DateTime in c#. 
I also need to compare this converted DateTime with current dateTime, I will be using this in comparison in Linq

Comment: google for `DateTime.ParseExact`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact`. Also your problem statement and code shown have nothing to do with Linq. The code below assumes the hours are in 24 hour format, adjust accordingly if that is not the case and provide an am/pm flag.

```
string date = "2017-03-29";
string time  = "09:30";
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date+time, "yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm", null);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say the same as @Sam, but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

```
string date = "2017-03-29";
string time = "09:30";

string dateTimeString = string.Format("{0} {1}", date, time);

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that the `Kind` of the resulting DateTime is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. Convert it as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Using the variables provided:

```
  string dateTime = date + " " + time;
  DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime);
```